# What is the status of Django Row based permission?

Tags: django, permissions, row

Is the Django **Row Level Permission** ready to use in application development? Or is it just a hook so far that require third party component to work properly?

As of Django 1.2, syncdb didn't create any special tables/fields to handle Row Level Perimission.

If not available, what is the best, dependable implementation available as open source that integrates well with Django?

Answer (score 1):

The Django [wiki page](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/RowLevelPermissions) says:

> A couple years ago, a branch in Django's repository was created to explore implementing finer-grained permissions (at the level of individual objects, rather than at the level of model classes). That branch is long since dead; it has not seen a commit in over two years, and likely will never be updated or integrated into Django in any meaningful way.

Comment: yes, that is what I see in docs. But, in DJango 1.2, we have a hook to implement row based permissions (I see modified code), though its just a hook so far.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not built in, but check out [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian)